# In MongoDb @CreatedBy getting null with springBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, auditing

I am using spring annotations `@CreatedBy` for createdBy and `@LastModifiedBy` for updatedBy-

```
@CreatedBy
@Field(value = "createdBy")
private String createdBy;

@LastModifiedBy
@Field(value = "updatedBy")
private String updatedBy;
```

Also i have used `@EnableMongoAuditing` this annotation in the main application.

And created a class which implements `AuditorAware` like below-

```
@Component
public class UserAudtiting implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

        String uname = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        return Optional.of(uname);
    }
}
```

So when i am using some post method to save data , I am getting **"createdBy":null** in response.

What should i do for this? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing),

> First, note that only entities that have a @Version annotated  field
>   can be audited for creation (otherwise the framework will  interpret a
>   creation as an update).

Add `@Version` in your entity.

Comment: I struggled a lot but adding the version finally worked for me. When inserting version is 1 and after the first update version is 2.

Comment: BTW, that's a couchbase doc, not a mongo doc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable auditing we need to add  to Spring configuration. XML or JAVA Config, either way

> Spring XML Configuraton

```
<mongo:auditing />

<mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="blog-tests" />
</bean>
```

> Spring Java Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.abc.xyz.repository")
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "test", "samp".toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "test");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

In order to use @CreatedBy and @LastModifiedBy you need to tell Spring who is a current user.

First add user related fields to your audited class:

```
@CreatedBy
private String createdBy;

@LastModifiedBy
private String lastModifiedBy;
```

Then create your implementation of AuditorAware that will obtain current user (probably from session or Spring Security context – depends on your application):

```
public class UserAudtiting implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
      // get your user name here
      String uname = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
      return Optional.of(uname);
    }
}
```

Last thing is to tell Spring Data MongoDB about this auditor aware class by little modification in Mongo configuration:

```
<mongo:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditor" />
<bean id="auditor" class="app.demo.UserAudtiting "/>
```

More details here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/auditing-entities-in-spring-data-mongodb.html

Comment: I am using spring maven project.So where should i add spring configuration? in pom.xml?

Comment: @Sonal Which version of Spring are you using? You can do either way, using XML as mentioned above or Java way. Will Update the answer. Please give it a try and hope it works. Let me know in case if you face any issues.

Comment: I am using spring boot model version- 4.0.0 and version-2.1.1 release. And I am getting an error in pom.xml while using spring configuration as mentioned above.

Comment: @Sonal Error in pom.xml? So you tried Spring Java config or Spring XML config ?

Comment: I tried it in Spring xml config still getting error.Can you please help me out regarding this !

Comment: @Sonal Just create a new java config class and copy-paste the above Spring Java Configuration described in the answer with your parameters.

Comment: I have already created mongo credentials.What should i do then?

Comment: @Sonal. Then skip that part and autowire mongo like  `@Autowired
    private Mongo mongo;`

Comment: Where should i pass mongo object? Because when i skip that line i am getting error below that line and goes on.

Comment: @Sonal Let's make it minimal and simple. Add this in your newly created config class. `@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoApplicationConfiguration {}`

Comment: @Sonal What is the issue you facing. Please debug and ensure nothing is null or breaking.